# Como retornar valor vazio em coluna?

Tags: sql

Basicamente a lógica deveria ser a seguinte. Retornar as ACs (aeronaves) que tem o componente **RCF6709** instalado (case 1) ou não instalado (case 0). Vejam:

1. Buscar as aeronaves ativas no `AC_Master`;
2. Considerando que deve ter 1 `pn` **RCF6709** por aeronave, fiz o case para contar `1` *(OK)* ou `0` *(Não está instalado)*;
3. Acredito que o erro está na linha onde coloquei `WHERE A.PN IN ('RCF6709')`, pois hoje a query está retornando tudo que está instalado (case 1). Porém quando extraio o relatório bruno, identifico que existem 5 Acs (aeronaves) que não possuem esse `pn` instalado.

```sql
SELECT B.AC,
A.PN,
COUNT (DISTINCT (A.AC)) AS "Nº OF CONTROLS",
B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES AS "TYPE/SERIES",
(CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT (A.AC)) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "CHECK"

FROM ODB.PLANNING A
LEFT JOIN ODB.AC_MASTER B
ON A.AC = B.AC

WHERE A.PN IN ('RCF6709')

AND B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES = 'ATR72-600'

AND B.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'

GROUP BY B.AC,
B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES,
A.PN
```

Comment: Sem conhecer a estrutura complica mas creio que você deva inverter sua order de joins FROM ODB.AC_MASTER B
LEFT JOIN ODB.PLANNING A aí testa a se a chave está nula , ou forma seria fazer um NOT EXITTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, tirando o WHERE A.PN IN ('RCF6709') e incluindo ele no LEFT JOIN como :

LEFT JOIN ODB.PLANNING A
    ON A.AC = B.AC
    AND A.PN = 'RCF6709

```
SELECT B.AC,
  A.PN,
  COUNT (DISTINCT A.AC) AS "Nº OF CONTROLS",
  B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES AS "TYPE/SERIES",
  CASE WHEN COUNT (DISTINCT A.AC) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "CHECK"
FROM ODB.AC_MASTER B
LEFT JOIN ODB.PLANNING A
ON A.AC = B.AC
AND A.PN = 'RCF6709'
WHERE B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES = 'ATR72-600'
AND B.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY B.AC,
  B.AC_TYPE ||'-'|| B.AC_SERIES,
  A.PN
```